# File /etc/modprobe.d/dummy.conf ignored on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

With Ubuntu 16.04, I have the following file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/dummy.conf
```

With the following content:

```
options dummy numdummies=12
```

And it works fine!

However, with Ubuntu 18.04, this isn't working anymore...

On Bionic, I have to manually run:

```
rmmod dummy
modprobe dummy numdummies=12
```

Then, it works!

So, how to do this automatically on Ubuntu 18.04 (new standard)?

Thanks!

Comment: No one knows about this?!

Comment: Looks like a bug... Reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1774731

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04, in the file

```
/lib/modprobe.d/systemd.conf
```

comment or edit this line:

```
"options dummy numdummies=0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty `/etc/modprobe.d/systemd.conf` file to override the `/lib/modprobe.d/systemd.conf` file that contains `options dummy numdummies=0`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a bug, that's "*by design*" (although I guess some people would strongly disagree that "design" could be applicable to `systemd` in general).

As can be seen from [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1774731/comments/19), the issue has been tracked down to `/lib/modprobe.d/systemd.conf` where `systemd` developers plainly and without a qualm say in comments: "…

> When bonding module is loaded, it creates `bond0` by default due to `max_bonds`
>   option default value `1`. *This interferes with the network configuration
>   management / networkd, as it is not possible to detect whether this bond0 was
>   intentionally configured by the user, or should be managed by
>   networkd/NM/etc*. Therefore **disable** bond0 creation. `options bonding max_bonds=0` *Do the same for* `dummy0`.

…"

For e. g., if you'd try to modify the module parameter in the way that Ubuntu's documentation cues you'd see that finally `modprobe` tries to load it so:

`…/dummy.ko numdummies=12 numdummies=0`

And the latest given arg option effectively overrides its previous occurrences.