# Ubuntu 18.04: How to create a persistent dummy network interface

Tags: networking, 18.04, interface, netplan

I am trying to create a dummy network interface on a Ubuntu 18.04 server. Here is how I would do it on my previous Ubuntu 16.04 servers:

In `/etc/network/interfaces.d/dummy.cfg`, write:

`auto dummy0
iface dummy0 inet static
  address 192.168.98.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0`

And then add `source /etc/network/interfaces.d/dummy.cfg` in `/etc/network/interfaces/`

From what I understand, Ubuntu 18.04 does not use `/etc/network/interfaces` anymore, we should use `netplan` instead. Apparently `netplan` does not support the creation of virtual interface (!) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nplan/+bug/1743200.

I can create the dummy interface with the iproute2 toolkit instead:

`$ ip link add dummy0 type dummy
$ ip addr add 192.168.98.1/24 dev dummy0
$ ip link set dummy0 up`

But this interface will disappear after reboot, as one would expect.

How can I create such a dummy network interface that will persist after reboot?

Comment: Please check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335284/how-can-we-create-multiple-dummy-interfaces-on-linux

Comment: @Arun I checked this question. I already did this configuration, the interfaces are not up on server boot.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1112247/54131

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem on 18.04 server and directly used the systemd-networkd way of configuring interfaces:

I created 2 files in `/etc/systemd/network/`:

1. `10-dummy0.netdev`

   ```
   [NetDev]
   Name=dummy0
   Kind=dummy
   ```
2. `20-dummy0.network`

   ```
   [Match]
   Name=dummy0

   [Network]
   Address=192.168....
   Address=fe80::.....
   ```

On boot the dummy interface is created automatically with IPv4 and IPv6 addresses an is shown in `ip addr` . Also `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` should create the interface.

I filed a bug on netplan, please support:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1774203

The docs:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.netdev.html#
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html#
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#

Comment: On 16.04, I needed to `systemctl enable systemd-networkd` before the `restart`.

Comment: The same appears to be the case for later releases of ubuntu. (20.04 as of today)