# Ubuntu 18.04 configure but disable network interface

Tags: networking, systemd-networkd

I created a dummy0 interface, (which is not currently supported by netplan) with systemd-networkd config syntax, as shown in my answer here:

[Ubuntu 18.04: How to create a persistent dummy network interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050353/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-create-a-persistent-dummy-network-interface)

But I would like to have it disabled on boot (not come up, but be configured). How can I achieve this in 18.04 ?

I would like to manually enable the interface with `ip link set dummy0 up`.