# Persistent network setup on live USB with persistence

Tags: xubuntu, live-usb

I have a Xubuntu Live USB with persistence on my pendrive and I want to do a specific network setup that should be persistent. I use this method now but I've tried some others:

[Ubuntu 18.04: How to create a persistent dummy network interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050353/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-create-a-persistent-dummy-network-interface)

Unfortunately, I have to execute `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` after reboot, because I can't see new, dummy interface since then. Is this because I use live USB? Is it possible to keep such network settings after restart without need to restart `systemd-networkd`?

Comment: So, NetworkManager is making my settings not persistent? I would like to have a dummy interface, so in such case I need to disable NetworkManager, because I cannot configure such interface in NetworkManager.

Comment: Thank you. I have managed to do the proper setup and persistent setup using netplan.